# It is correct to ask and answer your own question even when your question is about an error that you make?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

The past three days I've been struggling with an error in my Android app. I literally spent these three days trying a lot of tutorials, including the officials of course, and reading a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow.

These don't help a lot. Today I found my error; it was like a recopilation of all these tutorials and questions, but not exactly the same.

It it OK to create a question and answer it myself even if my solution is a mix of others solutions??

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer